Show that a harmonic function has no local maxima and minima
Given a differentiable function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a point $a \in U$ is called a critical point of $f$ (or a singular point) when $d f(a) = 0$, that is,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a) = \cdots = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(a) = 0.
$$
A critical point $a$ is said to be non-degenerate when the Hessian matrix at that point is invertible, that is,
$$
\operatorname{det}\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(a)\right) \neq 0.
$$

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function defined on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e., $f \in C^2$ and satisfies
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 0
$$
at every point in $U$. Assume that the critical points of $f$ are all non-degenerate. Show that $f$ has no local maxima or minima.

My attempt: A possible approach to demonstrate this would be to examine the behavior of $f$ near its critical points using Taylor's formula up to the second order. Since the function is harmonic, the second-order partial derivatives must satisfy the Laplace equation, which might imply specific behavior around critical points that prevents local extrema. But I'm stuck in this question.
Any suggestions on how to solve this question would be greatly appreciated.

It might be proved by "Maximum principle". Look at https://www.quora.com/How-the-laplace-equation-tells-that-there-is-no-local-extrema

As in the comment, the Laplacian can be thought as curvature operator which vanishes throughout its domain if acting on a harmonic function , i.e., $\nabla^2f(a)=0$. It can be intuitively illustrated as a flat region as in the "quora plot"
From mean value theorem.
$$
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})\rm d\theta
$$ for 2D where $r$ the radius
or
$$
f(x_0)=\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_Sf\rm dS
$$
for 3D where $x_0$ is at the center of the sphere.
By successively shrinking the circle ($r$ for 2D) and the sphere ($S$ for 3D), it is not hard to reach the conclusion.
I started above formulation but realized to find the references instead since I know that this is a classic problem and the proofs can be found in many textbooks: 1) the most famous one Theoretical Hydrodynamics, page 94, section 3.74; 2) Mathematics Applied to Deterministic Problems in the Natural Science
page 571, Sec.16.1; also Lecture Note...
This might not answer your question, but do hope to be helpful. Please view it as a long comment.
